# Error compiling LibGdx HTML module when using libgdx-utils library

Tags: java, libgdx, build.gradle

I've downloaded latest version of **GDX-Setup** utility and run it:

`java -jar gdx-setup.jar`

Than I've created empty project with html module included (**libgdx-utils** is only marked as 3rd-party extension).

[image]

Here compatibility with 1.9.5 libgdx version, but my version is 1.9.10

Generated **build.gradle** is following:

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.0.9'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.8'


    }
}

allprojects {

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "my-gdx-game"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.8'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.13.4:sources"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils:libgdx-utils:0.13.4"

    }
}
```

After that I ran: 
`./gradlew clean build`

As result I faced build failed with the following output:

```
> Task :html:compileGwt
Compiling module com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinition
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'net.dermetfan.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TreeFileChooser'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/.../.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.dermetfan.libgdx-utils/libgdx-utils/0.13.4/aabe6c69e3a8bee6e0a56f954f377631a3c2f720/libgdx-utils-0.13.4-sources.jar!/net/dermetfan/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/TreeFileChooser.java'
         [ERROR] Line 158: The method getObject() is undefined for the type Tree.Node
         [ERROR] Line 185: The method getObject() is undefined for the type Tree.Node
         [ERROR] Line 126: Cannot instantiate the type Tree.Node
         [ERROR] Line 127: The method setObject(FileHandle) is undefined for the type Tree.Node
         [ERROR] Line 97: Cannot instantiate the type Tree.Node
         [ERROR] Line 196: The method getObject() is undefined for the type Tree.Node
   [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files

> Task :html:compileGwt FAILED
```

Is it possible to use **libgdx-utils** with latest **libgdx** version *1.9.10*?
Is there some workaround for HTML libgdx module? or it is totally incompatible?

**P.S.**
Java Version: *1.8.0_181*.
Gradle Wrapper Version: *5.4.1*

Comment: The `Tree.Node` changes were introduced in 1.9.10, so they are in fact totally incompatible. As a workaround you can probably just use 1.9.9, there weren't many changes between the two versions. You could also make a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils) and update the project.

Comment: thx for your reply, I think I will try to exclude TreeFileChooser by some gradle build script. Or will try to fix it by my own.